# Read dataframe in one method within a class and call it in another within same class

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do i read the dataframe that I opened using QFileDialog in one method by calling it from another method and plot it? I am using PyQT5 one to read the text file and convert into a dataframe and the other button to plot the data. Please help!

```
def ButtonActionRead(self):
    print("Button Pressed")
    self.open_dialog_box()

def open_dialog_box(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    if filename[0]:
        f = open(filename[0], 'r')

        with f:
            df = pd.read_csv(f, 
                      sep='\t', 
                      names= ["ElementID","Load"])
                      self.Read_DataPressed == 1
            print(df)
    return df
def ButtonActionPlot(self):
    # if self.Read_DataPressed == 1:
    df = self.open_dialog_box(filename[0])
    print(df)
    # Plot the dataframe
```

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: it does not print the df

Comment: Where does it not print the df ? In ButtonActionPlot or open_dialog_box ? Is open_dialog_box executed (add a print statement before filename) ?

Comment: ButtonActionPlot

Comment: I want to access the dataframe in the plot QPushbutton in order to plot the data

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7I8nNK4j2g

Comment: I essentially want to reproduce the above youtube example but be able to read the data from a text or excel file and then plot it

Comment: one button to read the dataframe and another to plot it

Comment: I want the file that i open using the qdialog to pass into the ButtonActionPlot method so i can plot it

Comment: thank you @SyKer. I am a newb and just noticed no need to say thanks but you just solved 12 hours of research! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that it is hard to troubleshoot your issue without a minimal reproducible example but I can see a couple of problems;

1. Your function `open_dialog_box` does not take arguments, yet you call it with an argument later on;

```
def open_dialog_box(self):
    # ... your logic ... 

def ButtonActionPlot(self):
    #                            here
    df = self.open_dialog_box(filename[0])
```

2. You don't need to open the file before loading it in `pandas`;

```
def open_dialog_box(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    if filename[0]:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename[0], sep='\t', 
                      names= ["ElementID","Load"])

        self.Read_DataPressed == 1

        return df
```

**Solution, maybe:**

```
def open_dialog_box(self):
    # create a class variable 
    # to be accessed by any functions in your class
    # idealy, create it in __init__
    self.dataframe = None

    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()

    if filename[0]:
        self.dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename[0], sep='\t', 
                      names= ["ElementID","Load"])

        self.Read_DataPressed = 1

def ButtonActionPlot(self):

    # if the dataframe is loaded
    if self.Read_DataPressed == 1:

        # access the dataframe class variable
        print(self.dataframe) 

        # reset that for next time
        self.Read_DataPressed = 0

        # ... happy plotting ...
```